# Is application is runned under IIS or VS web-server

Tags: asp.net

How to determine whether asp.net (mvc2) application is running under IIS (7) or VS internal web-server?

Clarification why I need this: I'm composing different dependency graph for IoC-container (ninject) that depends on the workaround (develop - when local VS, and production - when IIS)

Or may be another great solution so I can simply differ 3 workarounds: local (VS), test server (IIS) or production server (IIS). How in this case to differ the server? By PC name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could look at `System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.ModuleName` to see what process your ASP.NET app is running in.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with Visual Studio 2010, you can have a specific web.config file for each environment using transformations (and adding a special appSetting for each environment). Check out the following links:

- [Configuration-Specific web.config Files](https://www.drdobbs.com/windows/configuration-specific-webconfig-files/224201017)
- [Web Deployment with VS 2010 and IIS](https://web.archive.org/web/20120710063032/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/webdevtools/archive/2009/02/04/web-deployment-with-vs-2010-and-iis.aspx)